# .NET 6, Nunit and Assembly in subfolder loading

Tags: .net, nunit

I'm trying to convert a project from .NET Framework to .NET 6. Previously, we used the "probing privatepath" to tell .NET to look for Assemblies in other subdirectory, but now we can not do this in .NET 6.

For the main program, I attached a method to the event AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving to manually load an assembly from the subdirectory, but I can not do this on NUnit. Tried on SetUpTextFixture OneTimeSetUp but it didn't work.

The DLL of the test projects are in the main output folder, but I need to references some DLLs that can't be on the output folder, but on their dedicated subfolder. I've referenced them in the "references" of the test projects, but when they try to be autoloaded I receive the FileNotFoundException. I would be really happy to use the AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath, in SetUpTextFixture. Is there a way to put in a very small class, being sure to be the first thing to be executed, not using anything from the subfolders assembly?

I'm running using ReSharper test runner in local, TeamCity in our CI/CD, using NUnit 4.0.1 and Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 17.8.0

Comment: Please edit your question to include what runner you are using, e.g. nunit-console, vs test explorer, etc. That runner is what loads your tests.

Comment: Absolutely right, I forgot it.